# Piecewise function and continuity

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

The function $$f(x)=\left\{ 
\begin{array}{lcl}
-4 x^2+2 &\mbox{ if }&x\geq 2\\
d -x &\mbox{ if }&x<2\\
\end{array}
\right.$$

is continuous at $x=2$ if and only if $d=$?

Anyone care to explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: We need $-4x^2+2$ and $d-x$ to agree when $x=2.$

Comment: That's it exactly! The upshot is that we need the upper and lower limits to agree at $x=2$, so since both pieces of the piecewise function are continuous at $x=2,$ then we need the pieces to agree.

Comment: @downvoter: Care to explain the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

for continuity we need $\lim_{x\uparrow 2}f(x)= f(2)=\lim_{x\downarrow 2} f(x)$